# How can I change the selection by using Dropdownlist in html-page?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

I use a dropdownlist and I want to change the selection by using the dropdown list. But it seems that the  selected item didn't reach the JS-function.

What do I wrong?

DropDownList

```
 <td class="selection">
                        @Html.DropDownList("id",
                             new SelectList(Model.Index, "Id", "Display"),
                             "-- Select edition --",
                             new
                             {
                                 @onchange = "javascript:SelectWeek(Display)"
                             })
                    </td>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    SelectWeek = function (value) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SongList", "Home")",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                year: value.substr(0, value.indexOf('-')).trim(),
                week: value.substr(value.indexOf('-') + 1, value.length - value.indexOf('-')).trim()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.status) {
                    alert(result.message);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.location.href = result.url;
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

In the controller

```
public IActionResult Songlist(int year, int week)
{
    if (year == 0 || week == 0)
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just watch the on change event with JavaScript since you're already using it? Like so:

```
 document.getElementById('yourIdHere').addEventListener('change',function(e){
       SelectWeek((this).value);

     });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view, call the dropdown "Display" and pass selected text to your javascript function. Note that double quotation marks need to be escaped.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Display",
    new SelectList(Model.Index, "Id", "Display"),
    "-- Select edition --",
    new
    {
        @onchange = @"javascript:SelectWeek($(""[id='Display'] :selected"").text())"
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this simple solution. JS is still a challenge for me.

```
                <td class="selectie">
                    @Html.DropDownList("PeriodSelection",
                         new SelectList(Model.Index, "Id", "Display"),
                         "-- Selecteer hitlijsteditie --",
                         new
                         {
                            // @onchange = "javascript:SelectWeek(Value)"
                         })
                </td>
```

... and the JavaScript.

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#PeriodSelection').on("change", function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').text();

            var year = selectedValue.substr(0, selectedValue.indexOf('-')).trim();
            var week = selectedValue.substr(selectedValue.indexOf('-') + 1, selectedValue.length - selectedValue.indexOf('-')).trim();

            window.location.href = '/Home/Songlist?year=' + year + '&week=' + week + '';
        });
    </script>
}
```